# C function parameter optimization: (MyStruct const * const myStruct) vs. (MyStruct const myStruct)

Tags: c, optimization, pointers, constants, pass-by-value

Example available at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/PmhyMT):

```
int passByConstPointerConst(MyStruct const * const myStruct)
int passByValueConst       (MyStruct const         myStruct)
```

Would you expect a compiler to optimize the two functions above such that neither one would actually copy the contents of the passed MyStruct?

I do understand that many optimization questions are specific to individual compilers and optimization settings, but I can't be designing for a single compiler.  Instead, I would like to have a general expectation as to whether or not I need to be passing pointers to avoid copying.  It just seems like using `const` and allowing the compiler to handle the optimization (after I configure it) should be a better choice and would result in more legible and less error prone code.

In the case of the example at [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/PmhyMT), the compiler clearly is still copying the data to a new location.

Comment: Before trying to optimize parameter passing, you should check if it is really needed. Do some measurements and profiling. It will probably show you that in most cases it won't be needed.

Comment: It's possible that they're allowing for the structure to be modified by async code. The lack of a `volatile` modifier should indicate that this isn't a concern, but the compiler may not have this degree of optimization.

Comment: This cannot be optimized away, so a compiler should not do that.

Comment: The SOP is already to pass by pointer and I was suggesting to my coworkers that perhaps we could write more legible code and leave optimization as a separate matter (in this case).  The volatile question did enter into this discussion.  As to not being able to optimize this away...  an explanation would be much more helpful than such a statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case (passing a const pointer to const) no copying occurs.

In the second case, copying does occur and I would *not* expect that to be optimized out if for no other reason because the address of the object is taken and then passed through an ellipsis into a function and from the point of view of the compiler, who knows what the function does with that pointer?

More generally speaking, I don't think changing call-by-value into call-by-reference is something compilers do. If you want copy by reference, implement it yourself.

Is it theoretically possible that a compiler could detect that it could just convert the function to be pass-by-reference? Yes; nothing in the C standard says it cannot..

Why are you worrying about this? If you are concerned about performance, has profiling shown copy-by-value to be a significant bottleneck in your software?

Comment: My colleagues were concerned about performance and I was curious if we could separate performance from coding technique in this particular case (regardless of the any actual performance issue).  I don't follow from your response why, given the second declaration, the compiler could not simply see the const nature in the callee and the non-volatile (not specified volatile) nature in the caller and realize that no copy is needed.

Comment: How can the compiler realize that no copy is needed when the address is being passed through an ellipsis to another function? Perhaps that other function behaves badly and casts the 'const' away? The compiler must be able to *prove* that its optimizations won't break the code, and while it's easy for you to ascertain that, the compiler probably can't in this case. With that said, when passing around structs you're better off to pass them either via pointers, or if using C++ via references to save on unnecessary copying.

Comment: To parrot back (poorly, I'm sure), structs that are 'passed-by-value' are really passed by pointer (this seems related to what Kaz wrote) and then...?  It's up to the callee according to Kaz and if I read correctly, you leave it up in the air; though you also say it is copied.  Are you saying it is copied and then a pointer to the copy is passed through the function call?  Am I getting even slightly closer?

Comment: Correct - pass by value will make a copy because that's what the programmer asked. The compiler is free to generate code that actually passes a *pointer* to the copy instead of the copy itself, but the copy will always be made.

Answer (score 1):

This topic is addressed by the `comp.lang.c` FAQ:

http://c-faq.com/struct/passret.html

When large structures are passed by value, this is commonly optimized by actually passing the address of the object rather than a copy. The callee then determines whether a copy needs to be made, or whether it can simply work with the original object.

The const qualifier on the parameter makes no difference. It is not part of the type; it is simply ignored. That is to say, these two function declarations are equivalent:

```
int foo(int);
int foo(const int);
```

It's possible for the declaration to omit the const, but for the definition to have it and vice versa. The optimization of the call cannot hinge on this `const` in the declaration. That `const` is not what creates the semantics that the object is passed by value and hence the original cannot be modified.

The optimization has to preserve the semantics; it has to look as if a copy of the object was really passed.

There are two ways you can tell that a copy was not passed: one is that a modification to the apparent copy affects the original. The other way is to compare addresses. For instance:

```
 int compare(struct foo *ptr, struct foo copy);
```

Inside `compare` we can take the address of `copy` and see whether it is equal to `ptr`. If the optimization takes place even though we have done this, then it reveals itself to us.

Answer (score 1):

The second declaration is actually a direct request by the user to receive a *copy* of the passed struct.

`const` modifier eliminates the possibility of any modifications made to the local copy, however, it is does not eliminate all the reasons for copying.

Firstly, the copy has to maintain its address identity, meaning that inside the second function the `&myStruct` expression should produce a value *different* from the address of any other `MyStruct` object. A smart compiler can, of course, detect the situations that depend on the address identity of the object.

Secondly, aliasing presents another problem. Imagine that the program has a global pointer `MyStruct *global_struct` and inside the second function someone modifies the `*global_struct`. There's a possibility that the `*global_struct` is the same struct object that was passed to the function as an argument. If no copy was made, the modifications made to `*global_struct` will be visible through the local parameter, which is a disaster. Aliasing issues are much more difficult (and in general case impossible) to resolve at compilation time, which is why compilers usually won't be able to optimize out the copying.

So, I would expect any compiler to perform the copying, as requested.

Comment: `const` ought to keep me from doing things like casting to a `MyStruct *` and only allow `MyStruct const *`.  As to the global data issue, I thought that was the point of `volatile`.  Am I wrong?  Obviously if the caller passes a volatile `MyStruct` then it would have to be copied.

Comment: @altendky: `volatile`? I don't see how `volatile` is relevant to this issue at all. It isn't. `volatile` has absolutely nothing to do with aliasing. Actually, what would be relevant here is `restrict` qualifier, but it cannot be applied to non-pointer parameter declarations.

Comment: I thought that the risk of aliasing would be explicitly expressed by applying, in the caller, `volatile` to the variable to be passed.  The thought being that if you don't apply `volatile` then you are allowing the compiler to assume that aliasing is a non-issue in regards to optimization.

Comment: @altendky: You mean you are *proposing* that `volatile` should be redefined that way? I don't immediately think this is a viable proposal. Moreover, the facility that allows the user to assist the compiler is aliasing optimizations is already introduced through `restrict` keyword.

Comment: @altendky if that was the case `restrict` would not be needed.

Comment: C99 6.7.3.6 "An object that has volatile-qualified type may be modified in ways unknown to the implementation or have other unknown side effects."  It seems that perhaps while pointers are assumed to be at risk of aliasing unless defined with `restrict`, variables are instead assumed to not be at risk unless defined as 'volatile'.  I am certainly not proposing any changes to the standard, rather I am stating my perception and hoping that explanations will be provided if (when) I have perceived incorrectly.  If I'm too far off to be set straight here, perhaps you know of a good link I can read?